# JPA mapping error

Tags: java, rest, jpa, eclipselink, dao

I am trying to retrieve some data from an SQLite db. I am using JPA with EclipseLink as a provider and I am trying to build a REST API. I have my model classes, the class in which I do my queries. The servcie and the rest class in which I construct my URI.

This is my model class:

```
package com.vehicle.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;


/**
 * The persistent class for the "Vehicles" database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Vehicles\"")
@NamedQuery(name="Vehicle.findAll", query="SELECT v FROM Vehicle v")
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="\"Model\"")
    private String model;

    @Column(name="\"Name\"")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="\"Purchasing_date\"")
    private BigDecimal purchasing_date;

    public Vehicle() {
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPurchasing_date() {
        return this.purchasing_date;
    }

    public void setPurchasing_date(BigDecimal purchasing_date) {
        this.purchasing_date = purchasing_date;
    }

}
```

This is my DAO class:

```
package com.vehicle.dao;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import com.vehicle.model.Vehicle;


public class VehicleDAO {

    EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "example" );

    EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager( );


       public void fetchVehicle(){
           Query query = em.createQuery("Select v.name, v.model, v.purchasing_date from Vehicles v");
                      List<String> list = query.getResultList();

                      for(String e:list) {
                         System.out.println("Vehicle NAME :"+e);
                      }

       }


}
```

This is the service class that calls the method from my DAO class:

```
package com.vehicle.service;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.vehicle.dao.VehicleDAO;
import com.vehicle.model.Vehicle;


public class VehicleService {

    VehicleDAO vehicleDao = new VehicleDAO();

    public void getDefaultVehicle() {
        System.out.println("BLAAAAAA");
       vehicleDao.fetchVehicle();
    }
}
```

This class is the one in which I construct my rest URIs:

```
package com.vehicle.rest;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.vehicle.model.Vehicle;
import com.vehicle.service.VehicleService;


@Path("/vehicles")
public class VehicleRest {

VehicleService vehicleService = new VehicleService();

    @GET
    @Path("/getVehicles")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void getDefaultVehicleInJSON() {
        System.out.println("BLAAAAAAA");
        vehicleService.getDefaultVehicle();
    }
}
```

The thing is, that when I try to run this in the browser it gives me this error:

```
Aug 08, 2017 6:08:27 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [Select v.name, v.model, v.purchasing_date from Vehicles v]. 
[7, 13] The state field path 'v.name' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
[15, 22] The state field path 'v.model' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
[24, 41] The state field path 'v.purchasing_date' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
[47, 55] The abstract schema type 'Vehicles' is unknown.
```

I do not get it why. There is no schema, its just the default schema.

**EDIT:**

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
      version="2.0"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="example" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
      <class>com.vehicle.model.Vehicle</class>
       <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:C:/development.sqlite3" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: since it is a JPQL query throwing the exception (presumably ... you don't post the exception and its stack trace) then the REST part of the post is irrelevant. Is Vehicle a known entity type (specified in `persistence.xml`, or exclude-unlisted-classes set to false?)

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Why are you escaping table name and columns name? Try to write them without escaping, eg. @Table(name="Vehicles")

Comment: I generated the model class with the JPA tool and that is how it turned out.

Comment: I removed the escaping, but it did nothing.

Comment: The query inside the DAO class should point to the name defined in the table annotation, which is @Table(name="\"Vehicles\"") or to the class name, which is Vehicle ?

Comment: Your first issue is solved by Neil's answer.  You have another problem related to the table name used in your entity, as it does NOT match what you must have in the database.  Create a new question for it, and show the logs, but I believe it will likely be related to the use of quotes in your table name - this makes the table name case sensitive and requires JPA to pass in quotes when specifying the table in queries - your DB apparently doesn't like that for this table.

Comment: I solved the problem. The issue was that the url provided for my db was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be

```
Select v.name, v.model, v.purchasing_date from Vehicle v
```

You put `Vehicles` in your question. The entity name is `Vehicle` (same as class).

Comment: I modified my query but now I get this error: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: Vehicles)
Error Code: 1
Call: SELECT "Name", "Model", "Purchasing_date" FROM "Vehicles"
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Vehicle sql="SELECT "Name", "Model", "Purchasing_date" FROM "Vehicles"")

Comment: It seems like the table is not found.

Comment: Can I somehow check if the connection to the db is made ?

Comment: You need to create the tables, before running queries, and JPA provides properties to do just that http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/persistence.html#schema-generation  as per any basic JPA reference docs say

Comment: If the table is "already created" then you don't get "no such table"

Comment: Then how was it possible to generate the model class from the table ? I generated it with the JPA tool.

Comment: who knows what is "jpa tool". The JPA spec provides no such thing. This answer fixes your query error. The schema error is something else either way